# css changed - inserted element is not visible

Tags: jquery, css

`title` is initially hidden.

Its css is changed (click on `btnview`) but new inserted `title` (click on `btninsert`) is not visible?

How to get it visible automatically by inserting (if previously `btnview` is clicked)?

Of course it can be done by `$('.title').show()` but what is then the purpose of `$('.title').css(...)` function?

```js
$('.btnview').on('click', function(){
$('.title').css('display', 'block');
});

$('.btninsert').on('click', function(){
var str = "<div class='title'>lorem</div>";
$(str).insertBefore($('.title').eq(0));
});
```

```css
.title{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<br>
<button class='btnview'>VIEW</button>
<button class='btninsert'>INSERT</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check visibility of previous `.title` then use `.show()` or `.css('','')` to display/hide added title.

```js
$('.btnview').on('click', function(){
$('.title').css('display', 'block');
});

$('.btninsert').on('click', function(){
var str = "<div class='title'>lorem</div>";
if($('.title').eq(0).css("display")=='block'){
  $(str).insertBefore($('.title').eq(0)).css('display','block'); // or .show()
}
else{
  $(str).insertBefore($('.title').eq(0))
}
});
```

```css
.title{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<br>
<button class='btnview'>VIEW</button>
<button class='btninsert'>INSERT</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.title').css('display', 'block');` only selects all current elements having class `title` and make their display block. It wont work for future elements.

Instead you can create two classes one with `display:none` and other with `display: block` and then use `addClass` and `removeClass` methods.

Comment: but `addClass` and `removeClass` also affects only existing `titles` and wont work for future elements. What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make a function result work for elements added in the future. The easiest way to do it is to use a container element instead, and adding the rule to its children so any new children get also impacted.

```js
$('.btnview').on('click', function(){
$('#titles_holder').removeClass('titles-hidden');
});

$('.btninsert').on('click', function(){
var str = "<div class='title'>lorem</div>";
$(str).insertBefore($('.title').eq(0));
});
```

```css
.titles-hidden .title{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="titles_holder" class="titles-hidden">
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<div class='title'>lorem</div>
<br>
<button class='btnview'>VIEW</button>
<button class='btninsert'>INSERT</button>
</div>
```

As to answer your specific question:

Take `<div class="title">` when you do `$('.title').css('display', 'block');` it simply becomes `<div class="title" style="display:block;">`. So when you add again `<div class="title">` it does not have the style too! You could use a variable to keep track or weter or not the button got clicked and directly add the title with the correct style.

Comment: of course I can use variable and additional coding but if something is called `change css` I'm expecting - `change css` and not `change css but for existing elements only`.

Comment: This is because it changes the CSS of the target element, not the CSS rules. You could target the CSS rule itself and change that... It would still be additional coding tough.

Comment: if the additional coding will affect NEW `titles` - it's ok. That's the question. How to make new titles having a changed css rule?

Comment: The answer stands, the additional container's class can be used to affect all children, past future and present.